# PHP does not add to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, addition

I have the following code which updates a field in a database table to add 1 to it. The ID should have a variable being posted to it. Can anyone see where this is going wrong?

EDIT: Sorry, I completely forgot to mention the actual problem. The database is not updating the field.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","**","***","***");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE base SET thumbdown = thumbdown + 1 WHERE id = $_POST['id']");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? @googleyberry

Comment: The query looks fine.  Just a wild guess, but could you please print out the $_POST['id'] variable?  My guess is it is either not set, or not set to an integer value you are expecting it to be set to.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer This is what is baffling me. The variable is set and I have also tried printing it as a variable as David said.

Comment: you gotta surround the $_POST with braces.

Answer (score 3):

You wont get the `$_POST['id']` parsed in to the string correctly as it is an array. You must enclose it in braces:

```
"UPDATE base SET thumbdown = thumbdown + 1 WHERE id = '{$_POST['id']}'"
```

But remember (always!) to escape the variable first:

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE base SET thumbdown = thumbdown + 1 WHERE id = '{$id}'");
```

Comment: How do you know if the `id` field in the db table is an integer? Did I miss something?

Comment: I have it set to an integer. I have just tried this code, and it doesnt seem to be working either?

Comment: Then you must provide more detail. What is the output? Are there any errors displayed?

Comment: I have a system that is posting to the php script. I have confirmed that it is sending the variable 'id' correctly, for example, I can confirm that it sends over a '4' into the ID variable. There are no visible errors. If I hardcode a number into the script then it works just fine, but the issue seems to come from something to do with the variable.

Comment: @maciej There are no quotes around it in the query.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer, ok youre right. Escaping is more general though, and works with integers just as fine.

Comment: Then you probably don't have record with the provided `id` in the database. This is an `UPDATE` query, which does work only if the conditions in `WHERE` are met.

Comment: I have records with id's 1-294 - There is definitely one present.

Comment: Try `echo`ing the query, copy and pase to the databse console directly, and show us the output.

Comment: Also echo `mysqli_error()` output (just after the `mysqli_query()`) and see if something is wrong there.

Comment: If I put they query into the database console, using the number 4 where id should be, then I get it successfully added.